# ¿Obtener filas según el where que hay dentro de una columna?

Tags: sql, oracle

Estoy trabajando con Oracle y tengo una Tabla como esta:

| id | where  |
|----|--------|
| 1  | 1 = 1  |
| 2  | 1 != 1 |
| 3  | 1 != 2 |

No se como obtener las filas que den true en base a la columna where. En este caso se obtendrían las filas con ID 1 y 3.

EDIT.

Me gustaría realizar un 'select * from tabla Where', donde la condición del where sea lo que hay dentro de la columna Where. Que fuese iterando por filas determinando si la columna where es válida o no según el campo where de esa fila.

Por ejemplo en la fila 1 sería: 'select * from tabla where 1 = 1', en la dos:'select * from tabla where 1 != 1' y así sucesivamente.

Comment: podrias explicar mejor tu pregunta, realmente no entiendo que quieres hacer

Comment: @MauEspaña listo.

Comment: se mira mas como si quisieras hacer unas consultas secuenciales

Comment: @BetaM Está claro, realizando una sola query que se muestren las filas donde la comprobación de la columna 'where' sea true.

Comment: @MauEspaña ya, la realidad es que es una tabla para un menú. Este menú tiene +200 registros y se accede a este menú +10.000 veces al día. Hacer una consulta iterativa por cada fila cada vez que se muestra es lo que necesito evitar.

Comment: Entonces tal vez algo como `where `where` = 1`

Comment: Ahora el segundo where necesita estar dentro de las backticks por qué es una palabra reservada

Comment: ¿Tiene un ejemplo de datos más concretos para las condiciones, pues no encuentro que validez tiene una condición como "1 = 1" (que siempre da el valor lógico TRUE) o "1 != 1" (que siempre da el valor lógico FALSE)?